# Charset change by itself under Ajaxplorer

Tags: windows, apache, character-encoding, locale, pydio

I got a standard installation of AjaxPlorer 4.23 under Windows. The Diagnostic tools simply indicated "OK" to everything except the SSL part...

- The application is unzipped under http://some_domain.com/share
- I made sure to set locale in the bootstrap_conf.php to define("AJXP_LOCALE", "fr_FR.ISO-8859-1"); has we use some french characters like é, ç, è, â, ï...
- For some reason that I ignore up to now, one user might login, go to some specific folder named with french chars an he's receiving an error message from the fsAccess driver like : message=opendir(ajxp.fs://aaa744f141829e991d80a21d5dde850b/Réunion du 12 février 2013): failed to open dir: "fsAccessWrapper::dir_opendir" call failed
- I went into the diagnostic tools of Ajaxplorer to take a look at the LOCALE variable. It is now set to english United States 1252. I'm the owner of the server and I am the only one that as access to it so, for some reason the application change the encoding by itself....
- Recently, I had an issue with some users that try to access the application with IE10 and get a blank page displayed. I had the workarround with apache to force IE10 to emulate like IE9 (under LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so) and it works like a charm for this part.
- Is there any way that uncommenting this module into apache might let Ajaxplorer enough permission to change something to crash my French Encoding charset.
- When I restart my Apache server, all goes fine for a minute of two. Locale value is C, after this, I simply refresh the diagnostic tools and there ya go, Locale is now indicating english United States 1252 and all user that aren't log yet are getting difficulties to manade their folder / files with french accents.

Résumé : AJXP_LOCALE is set to fr_FR.iso-8859-1 after i do a restart on my apache server regarding to the dianostic tool into Ajaxplorer itself. After a couple of minutes, AJXP_LOCALE change by himself to english.United States 1252. If a restart my apache server, all goes fine for a couple of minutes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had a hint somewhere else...

My server itself was not set to the right locale (country, language). But I tought Ajaxplorer overwrite and simply discard the locale set by the server OS.

1. So under my windows server 2008 R2 I change United States to Canada and English for Français Canada.
2. Restart Apache
3. Set this value into bootsrap_conf.php define("AJXP_LOCALE", "fr_FR.ISO-8859-1");

Now when I check into the diagnostic tools under Ajaxplorer Locale is now define to French Canada instead of English_United States.

I am now able to browse under folder that contains french chars like é ç û and has well, interact with files.